# How do I select the rows with the most recent date in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table that has columns `employee_id`, `status`, and `update_date`. I'm trying to select all three columns on the condition that the `update_date` has to be the most recent (the values for status are initiated, completed, and not_applicable, so depending on that an employee_id could appear 3 times in the table).

The table has around 300 rows, but I know the output should contain around 50. I am very new to SQL.

The query I've tried is:

```
select employee_id, status, update_date 
from data 
where update_date = max(update_date)
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you seems want :

```
select d.employee_id, d.status, d.update_date 
from data d
where update_date = (select max(d1.update_date) 
                     from data d1 
                     where d1.employee_id = d.employee_id
                    );
```

Comment: I am having trouble executing/understanding this query, as there is only one table (I have renamed it in the original post to 'data'). What is t1 in your response?

Comment: @bayesian.asian. . . Same this would also `data` in `subquery`. See edit.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query works in most DMBS systems like MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQL-server. 
 
Keep in mind it also returns ties when a employee has the same MAX update_date.

```
   SELECT 
     *
    FROM (
      SELECT 
          employee_id
        , MAX(update_date) AS max_update_date     
      FROM
       table
      GROUP BY
       employee_id  
    ) AS table_max
    INNER JOIN
     table 
    ON
       table.employee_id = table_max.employee_id
     AND
       table.update_date = table_max.max_update_date
```